# Pointing remote Bitbucket repository to content in remote Github repository that pulls from local folder

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Basically my goal is to push to both my GH and BB remote repositories, or push to my GH from my local, and the BB repository pulls from my remote GH.

I tried following the instructions in: [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations/3195446#3195446) but I really don't understand and I've been tinkering with this all day.

I have two branches that I also want synced across both. Essentially at all times both repositories should mirror eachother perfectly.

I have one more person that will be connected, but only to the bitbucket repository. When they push to the BB repo, I want both my GH and BB repository to update.

How could I set this up? I also want to use the Github 2 app to push changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to tinker with local config, you could setup webhooks on both:

- [GitHub (webhook)](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)
- [BitBucket (post-hook)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management)

That supposes you have a server able to listen to the JSON payload emitted by those two hooks.
That listener will:

- detect the push done on one remote repo,

  - because of the `"canon_url": "https://bitbucket.org"` field.
  - because if the [`url` or `repository` field](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)
- and push to the other.